# TYPO3 file permission

Tags: permissions, typo3, fal

I would like to create a folder at the root level in TYPO3 so that I can access it without using the browser's address bar and open the files within it. These are video files. When I provide an absolute path in a File Mount, I can also select the videos as media elements in the backend. However, the video doesn't play properly on the frontend. How can I achieve this?

Comment: please specify: `root level` (web root or project root?) what does `doesn't play properly` mean? any error messages?

Comment: - public
- vendor
- videos.....
There are no errors. just won't play the video. and no thumbnail in the backend

Comment: first idea: is that folder protected in any way? (.htaccess, file permissions for apache/ nginx, ...). What error do you get in the browser debugger? What error do you get if you call the video directly in the browser?

Comment: There are no errors. The video ist just not loading. I can't call it directly in the browser. That is what i want. And no .htacess file. Just TYPO3 methods.

Comment: in the browser tools you should get a HTTP-response code (probably other than 200).
in the network-analyzing-tab you should see a request to the video for the webpage (like for any image), at least if you use the direct video-URL.